# Cannot route to required React Component using React-Router-DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to route to the component "Products" from my Homepage as per the product id from the item list from the Home Component. My page is getting routed to 'localhost:3000/id' but it is not getting the Products component. There are no errors that I faced. I fetched the data from the fake API and displayed the products on the home page. After clicking the product I want the page to route to "Product" component. The address is routing as expected but the component is not loading.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
  import {
   BrowserRouter as Router,
   Switch,
   Route,
   Link
    } from "react-router-dom";

   import Products from "./Products";

   interface Props {}

   interface ResponseData {
    id: number;
    price: number;
    description: string;
    image: string;
   }

   interface State {
    response: ResponseData[];
   }

export default class Home extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      response: [],
    };
  }
  getProductsData = async () => {
    const apiResponse = await    fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
    console.log(apiResponse);
    const responseData = await apiResponse.json();
    this.setState({
      response: responseData,
      });
     };

  componentDidMount() {
     this.getProductsData();
   }
   render() {
     const { response } = this.state;
     if (response.length === 0) {
       return <div className="loader">Loading the items.......     </div>;
    }
     return (
       <div >
         <div className="product-list">
           {response.map((resp) => (
              <Switch>
              <Link className = "product-cards" 
              to={`${resp.id}`} >
              <Route path={`${resp.id}`} component={Products}/>
               <div className="product-cards">
               <img src={resp.image} />
               <div className="product-description">{resp.description}</div>
                <div className="product-price">{resp.price}</div>
            </div>
            </Link>
           </Switch>
         ))}
       </div>
     </div>
    );
   }
 }
```

Comment: We may need quite a bit more context here. Can you provide us a more complete and comprehensive code example? Can you also explain in more detail what isn't working as expected? Is there an error? What is the observed versus expected result? What debugging steps have you taken already? Are you rendering any other routes? What is the value of `response` that you are mapping?

Comment: I added the complete code and explained my query better. Do I need to provide more info regarding this or is this sufficient?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that really added any useful information other than I can query what that `"https://fakestoreapi.com/products"` API returns. Why are you trying to render a route inside the link? What is rendering `Home`? Where are you rendering the `Router` and routes you want to navigate to from the links?

Comment: My query has been resolved. My mistake was trying to route within the link. Adding an external Route file solved th problem and I am able to make it work as per my requirement.

Comment: Great! I'm voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to replace your switch routes to App component and in this Home component just use a Link to redirect to the path you want.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={ Home } />
      <Route path="/:id" component={ Products } />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Home component return should be something like this:

```
return (
  <div className="product-list">
    {response.map((resp) => (
      <Link
        className = "product-cards" 
        to={`/${resp.id}`}
      >
        <div className="product-cards">
          <img src={resp.image} />
          <div className="product-description">{resp.description}</div>
          <div className="product-price">{resp.price}</div>
        </div>
      </Link>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```